# Pandas regex replace with multiple values and spaces in the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas code where I am trying to replace the names of countries with the string `<country>`.

```
df['title_type2'] = df['title_type']
countries = open(r'countries.txt').read().splitlines()    # Reads all lines into a list and removes \n.
countries = [country.replace(' ', r'\s') for country in countries]
pattern = r'\b' + '|'.join(countries) + r'\b'
df['title_type2'].str.replace(pattern, '<country>')
```

However I can't get countries with spaces (like South Korea) to work correctly, since they do not get replaced. The problem seems to be that my `\s` is turning into `\\s`. How can I avoid this or how can I fix the issue?

Comment: can you add a data sample too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to replace any space with *\s*.

Your pattern should rather include:

- `\b` - "starting" word boundary,
- `(?:...|...|...)` a non-capturing group with country names (alternatives),
- `\b` - "ending" word boundary,

something like:

```
pattern = r'\b(?:China|South Korea|Taiwan)\b'
```

Then you can do the replacement:

```
df['title_type2'].str.replace(pattern, '<country>')
```

I created test data as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Abc Taiwan', 'Xyz China', 'Zxx South Korea', 'No country name'],
    columns=['title_type'])
df['title_type2'] = df['title_type']
```

and got:

```
0      Abc <country>
1      Xyz <country>
2      Zxx <country>
3    No country name
Name: title_type2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out my actual mistake was not to assign `df['title_type2'] = df['title_type2'].str.replace(pattern, '<country>')`. Rookie mistake.